# Servletcontext in item writer class

Tags: java, spring, batch-file, servlets

I need to convert an XML to pdf. For this , I need read a xsl file which is inside my workspace in inputstream. This logic should be inside my  itemwriter class. How get the servletcontext inside my itemwriter class ?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't use the `ServletContext` you don't want to tie your whole application to the web especially not your batch jobs.

Comment: How to read the xsl file in inputstream?

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton bean ServletContextHolder with a `private static staticServletContext` field and

```
public static getServletContext() {
    return staticServletContext;
}
```

method.

Add initializing logic in any place where the servlet context is available. E.g. in a controller add `HttpServletRequest` parameter and call `request.getServletContext()` to assign the context to the static field of the ServletContextHolder bean.

Then just access the static field in the ItemWriter.

Alternatively you can store request in a thread local storage and get the context from the request. If the ItemWriter thread is called from a controller where request is available you can access the request.

Comment: I don't get the servletcontext inside writer class